# How do grab the main loop, with conditions, and output via shortcodes

Tags: functions, loop, shortcode

I don't have any code for this because I'm not sure how to begin. I created a category called "News". On my homepage I want to show the 3 most recent articles, but I need to output them using a shortcode so I can have it in my WYSIWYG.

My research is only showing me custom post types, and I'm not sure how I'd tweak that so it'd be the main loop.

Any resources would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do this in this manner?  Normally a section like this might be written to the page template somehow and not called via the content editor.   That being said, this should do what you need:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_xyz_news', 'xyz_news_query' );

function xyz_news_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => 'news',
    );
    $news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
        $html_out = '<ul>';
        while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
            $news_query->the_post();
            // Do stuff with each post here
            $html_out .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
        $html_out .= '</ul>';
    else : // No results
        echo "Nothing to show";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

Then in the editor for the page call the shortcode `[show_xyz_news]`.

Comment: Well, I have a design that has two columns of text, this content is in the page on WP. Below this content is 3 recent posts based on a category. The section after is more content that would be in the page on WP. I have no idea how to write all the content in the WYSIWYG and choose where to put the loop in the php file. I'd have to use ACF and build sections of the homepage each in it's own custom field. Using shortcodes is the only way I can think of putting it all in one place.

Comment: This broke my site, I had to revert so I'm unable to keep it running for you to see. In the source, right after the shortcode ended it removed the rest of the page's markup.

Comment: I removed `die;` and it worked. I added this shortcode after a paragraph in the WYSIWYG but on the front end it appeared before it.

Comment: this made my entire screen go white

Comment: Enable debug mode so you can see your error.  I'm using this exact code on a sandbox site with no issues.   Is 'news' the slug for your category?

Comment: Well...I enabled debug and re-pasted the code...and it works now. I have no idea how. Thanks for the help! I plan on calling another slug "events" so I can dupe this. How can I adjust my OP so it's not -1? The only thing I don't really understand is what `.=` is.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  In PHP the `.=` operator is concatenation, appending the new string to the existing value.  You can continue to lengthen the output that way.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php.  Don't forget to mark this answer and if you edit your question to be a little more inline with guide here it should help with the rating:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask